# The boss asks to return money?

Tags: work-environment, salary, ethics

Ok, the situation is:

I have just started with a very fresh (6 months-old) company and the source code of the app is not the greatest, the time of few deliveries were missing and I got to the point when the boss asked me "Why things are late?"

The next day my boss said, "Oh you know what, I actually sent you a salary of a wrong person, could you please return it asap" - My reply was: "Once I receive someone else salary, will do that in the same minute", the boss didn't like it, saying: "Well, I sent you money just right now, and I have to pay for the office, marketing, etc etc, so if we could speed up things.." that would be brilliant. I said that nothing is going to change my mind, and I will return money as soon as I receive.

There are two days have gone, money haven't arrived yet and the boss doesn't follow up on this topic (strange, isn't it?). So my question is... what would you do in this situation.

PS. Personally I am feeling down, as I usually like to create the environment of trust at the workplace.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is?  The boss asked you to return money you have not yet recieved, and you said you would when you get it.  What is the question

Comment: @Chad `So my question is... what would you do in this situation.`

Comment: "and I have to pay for the office, marketing, etc etc" So he doesn't have enough of a financial buffer to support one salary going wrong? Red flag. I'd make sure your resume is fresh and up to date...

Comment: Have you been paid your regular salary?

Comment: @chipperyman573 - That is not the type of question we deal with on SE.  I still do not see a problem that requires action here anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I may be wrong, but I think what you are getting at is you are concerned that he didn't make a mistake and asked you for some other reason, (presumably because of serious financial problems).

If the extra money hasn't come into your account within a couple of days of you receiving your usual salary, just say something like "Hey, I never did get that extra money, did you manage to sort it out?" He may have just managed to contact the bank and resolve it and never thought to bother you again.

You definitely did the right thing though to refuse to pay up.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to him about how you haven't received it. Request a meeting with him and HR to discuss it so that everything he says is recorded and official. That's not a big request because it's related to money, which is very serious. Ask for proof that the money was in fact sent (from accounting or payroll) and bring proof you never received it (bank statement, etc).

Comment: I like it. Thank you very much. The only issue that there is only one boss and the boss is HR as well. I might ask other people to join the conversation

Answer (score 1):

Tell your boss you have not received any salary. Do not give him your bank statement now as he has not asked for it officially, he made a mistake so if he produces proof of transfer then you produce proof that you have not received it.

Dont throw your financial status as it can be effectively used to make decisions concerning you...

Comment: It's a small company 3 people working, including me.

Comment: Dont just give in your financial doc till he produces something tangible...you might not know what he wants to see your financial info may be